# Check whether the email textbox value exists in database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to check the value in text box is present in database and clear the box if the value exists in the database without refreshing the whole page.

**HTML:**

```
<p>Email<input type="text" name="email" id="email" size=18 maxlength=50 required></p>
```

**Query:**

```
$echeck="select email from register where email='$email'";
$echk=mysql_query($echeck);
$ecount=mysql_num_rows($echk);
if($ecount!=0)
{
    echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
    var asign=document.getElementById(email);   //now show null value
    asign.value="";                
    </SCRIPT>");
}
```

If I use alert it will refresh the page.

```
window.alert('Email Id already exist');
```

Comment: try ajax on blur , change or according your need

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try to implement something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkMailStatus(){
    //alert("came");
var email=$("#email").val();// value in field email
$.ajax({
    type:'post',
        url:'checkMail.php',// put your real file name 
        data:{email: email},
        success:function(msg){
        alert(msg); // your message will come here.     
        }
 });
}

</script>

  <p>Email<input type="text" name="email" id="email" onblur="checkMailStatus()"size=18 maxlength=50 required></p>
```

your php: **checkMail.php**

```
$echeck="select email from register where email=".$_POST['email'];
   $echk=mysql_query($echeck);
   $ecount=mysql_num_rows($echk);
  if($ecount!=0)
   {
      echo "Email already exists";
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure because I have always used JQuery, however I try:
Source: [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp)
**HTML file**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkInput(){
            var email=document.getElementById('email').value.trim();
            if(email.length==0)
                 return;
            var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
              if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
                    if(xmlhttp.responseText==0){
                        document.getElementById('email').value='';
                        alert('Email already exists');
                    }
                else if(xmlhttp.responseText==1){
                      document.getElementById('email').value='';
                      alert('Invalid Email');      
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET","check.php?email="+email,true);
            xmlhttp.send();

        }

</script>
//I would use check mail button, to prevent accindental unfocus
<p>Email<input type="text" name="email" id="email" onblur="javascript:checkInput();" size=18 maxlength=50 required></p>
```

**check.php**

```
//This is a simple input check
//The way you check the value isn't secure, you should sanitaze the input
// consider PDO or MySQLi

//Check if email otherwise stop php and clean input
if(!filter_var($_GET['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
    echo '1';
    exit();
}

$echeck="select email from register where email='$_GET['email']'";
$echk=mysql_query($echeck);
$ecount=mysql_num_rows($echk);
if($ecount!=0){
    echo '0';
    exit();
}
else{
    echo '2';
}
```

Comment: elem.value returns undefined value

Comment: @saru now it should work(I have tested it on localhost)

Comment: if the textbox is empty it shows 'email alredy exist'

Comment: @saru Ok, it's because the invalid email and the query return the same code 0, I can add a line and send a different reply if the email isn't valid, otherwise just comment the alert function, let me know what would you like

Comment: I want to display alert only the email is exist in db.If the textbox is empty I don't want any alert...

Comment: @saru Ok, I have edited the php code and the js, now it doesn't do anything when the inout is empty and alert when the email is already present and invalid